# Links are mismatched in JQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-mobile

I got a new problem regarding JQueryMobile...
Let me explain flow of my listing application

country -> region -> categories-> subcategories->listing->detail page

This is my [home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POx6Q.png) (Default.aspx) !!

This is my [next page (region)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTaUN.png) (regions.aspx?_c=CA) !!

And This is my [categories page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHxQP.png) (categories.aspx) !!

the code of **`Home`** link is

```
<a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
```

Now the problem is when I click on the ***home*** link on categories page.. it redirects to Default.aspx ! no issue with this metter ! Now the actual problem starts now... When I click anyof the country on the Default.aspx it redirects to categories page rather than region page....

Got my problem ??

when there is fresh request my flow is like

**country -> region -> categories->**

But when I click on Home link on categorypage, my flow becames

**country -> categories->**

I have tried a lot !! But still didn't getting the solution !

Comment: Do you have data-rel="back" in the Home link on your category page?

Comment: First of all thanks for replying.. and no i have not included data-rel="back....

Look my defination of Homelink

 <a href="Default.aspx" data-theme="b">
   Home 
         </a>